# test API using POSTMAN with data file

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I need to test multiple POST endpoints using POSTMAN with data file. the data file contains array of JSON objects:

```
[{"id":"f9DpX"},{"id":"ofLrsYy6b"},{"id":"KJ04"},....]
```

I need to use the whole JSON array as POST body. when I opened POSTMAN runner and choose 'Data File', it shows the the array of JSON objects are break down to iterations and each iteration has only one 'id' even I specify the iteration for test to 1.

```
Iteration id
1         f9DpX
2         ofLrsYy6b
3         KJ04
...
```

what I really want is :

```
Iteration id
1         f9DpX,ofLrsYy6b,KJ04..
```

how can I do that in POSTMAN?

Comment: The format you have is the accepted format the JSON data file should be in, to work in the Collection Runner. You would need to have a single `id` key and the value would be all the individual values you have in the objects.

Comment: For example: `[{"id":"f9DpX,ofLrsYy6b,KJ04"}]`